# What is the most efficient way to find a subarray of elements in array in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array (`NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` doesn't matter): `SpecID` of specific files `ID`s (`109234`, etc.). And I have a large array of all files `ID`s : `FilesID`.
I need to check whether `FilesID` contains all the elements of `SpecID`.

So the question what is the fastest and most efficient way of doing this except simple comparing all the elements to each other in a loop. May be there are some standard method or efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use sets:

```
NSSet *specIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:specIDarray];
NSSet *fileIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:fileIDarray];

if ([specIDs isSubsetOfSet:fileIDs])
{
    // Your file IDs contains every ID found in specIDarray
}
```

For this to work efficiently, the objects should ideally be `NSNumber` objects, or if they are custom objects, they should override both `hash` and `isEqual:`. The efficiency of sets depends mostly on having a good `hash`. The Foundation classes, e.g. `NSNumber`, `NSString` etc have good hashes.

Also, if you can, load your IDs directly into sets rather than converting them from arrays as this will be slightly more efficient, but otherwise the above is probably as simple as it would get. There may be specialised algorithms which would perform better but only explore those options if the above is too slow.